# Can I use RakNet Networking in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, raknet

I want to create a multiPlayer online game with unity but unity networking class isn't efficient.
Is it anyway for using RakNet in unity instead of UN(unity networking API)?
and how can I use it in c# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i recall correctly RakNet is already being used by Unity by default but uses the networking class as a kind of wrapper for the RakNet API.